# print lines with specific number of specific char

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a big text saving lots of file paths and their information

```
# just for demostration
/a/b/c/d/e
/a/b/c/d
/a/b/c
/a/b
/a
/b/c
/b
/c/d
/c
....
```

I want to show only those with specific number of specific char, for instance,

1. with only one `/`
2. with no more than two `/`

so that I extract only root folders or only to first-level subfolders.

Comment: Just because that looks like it could have been produced by `find`, gnu’s find has a maxdepth option that you may find useful.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I know `find`. but I'm working on text data, not real file structure. Your `grep` solution is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an extended regular expression:

```
grep -E '^([^/]*/[^/]*){1,2}$' input
```

which results in these matches:

```
/a/b
/a
/b/c
/b
/c/d
/c
```

The regex syntax says:

- `^` - anchored to the beginning of the line
- `( ... )` - group the following bits together
- `[^/]*` - any non-forward-slash character, zero or more of them
- `/` - a forward-slash
- `[^/]*` - any non-forward-slash character, zero or more of them
- `{1,2}` - one or two of those groups
- `$` - anchored to the end of the line

Answer (score 4):

**`Awk`** solution:

-- with only one `/`:

```
awk -v sep=1 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/"; sep += 1 }NF == sep' file
```

The output:

```
/a
/b
/c
```

---

-- with no more than two `/`:

```
awk -v sep=2 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/"; sep += 1 }NF <= sep' file
```

The output:

```
/a/b
/a
/b/c
/b
/c/d
/c
```

---

- `sep` - variable; stands for directory *separator*'s count
- `FS` and `OFS` - are field separator and output field separator respectively
- `NF` - stands for *total number of fields*

---

If you need to combine the above approaches into a single `awk` command:

```
awk -v sep=1 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="/"; sep += 1 }(sep==2 && NF==sep) || (sep>2 && NF<=sep)' file
```

Comment: Thx. Good solutions! I chose the `grep` post as answer only because `grep` is easier to understand.

Comment: Is the setting of `OFS` even necessary in this context?

Comment: @steeldriver, in this narrow context - no. But it might be so in case if some field value would be changed for some purpose.